# backbone router does not pick up the function

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I tried to use backbone with a pushstate:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "/":            "homepage",
            "/questions":   "questions"
        },
        homepage: function() {
            console.log('why');
        },
        questions: function() {
            console.log('this is not working?');
        }
    });
    var the_app = new App();
    $("a").click(function(ev) {
        the_app.navigate( $(this).attr("href"), true);
        return false;
    });
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
})
```

The problem is that whenever I click a link like one of this:

```
<a href="/"> home </a>
<a href="/questions"> questions</a>
<a href="/justlink"> just link</a>
```

Location in the browser changes without reloading, but the function, associated with it and which I already defined in routes, does not executes.
Any idea what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-extend):

> **extend** `Backbone.Router.extend(properties, [classProperties])`
>
> [...] Note that you'll want to avoid using a leading slash in your route definitions:

You want your `routes` to look like this:

```
routes: {
    "":            "homepage",
    "questions":   "questions"
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ybPcg/